# Using JSON data from API GET to POST to another API via python script

Tags: python, scripting

So, I'm new to python and am struggling, self taught, and still learning to code. So be easy on me :)

I am using a script to get data from one source (Jira's API) and trying to use those results to post to another (PowerBi).

I've managed to successfully **get** the data, I just don't know how to pass the data to this other API.

I know how to use the GET and POST calls, it's just using the data from one to another than I can't seem to find anything about. Assuming since what I'm asking for is very specific?

edit: I also want to mention that while my get is asking for specific data, I'm getting more than I actually need. So I need a way to specify (hopefully) what data is actually being sent to PowerBi's API

```
import json
import requests

url = 'https://mydomain.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/search'

headers = { 'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
        'Authorization' : 'Basic 123456789' }

params = {
   'jql' : 'project IN (, PY, CH, NW, RP, DP, KR, DA, RE, SS, CR, CD, AB) AND issueType=incident AND statusCategory!=Done',
   'startAt': 0,
   'maxResults' : 50,
}

requestget = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)

if requestget.status_code == 200:
    print(json.dumps(json.loads(requestget.text), sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(",", ": ")))
else:
     print("None")
```

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if I miss understood what you were asking help on, but you could use this to send a POST request as json.

```
request = urllib.request.Request()#Put the powerbi api here
request.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8')

jsondata = #your json data
jsonBytes = jsondata.encode('utf-8')

#Has to be bytes

request.add_header('Content-Length', len(jsonBytes))
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request, jsonBytes)
```

You could go with a requests.post instead.

```
jsondata = #put json data here

headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(jsondata), headers=headers)
```

[Requests documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/)